# Correct way of removing a comma from last record from a hyperlink in a for loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I had the requirement where we had to remove a comma from the last record all the records were a hyperlink.
Ex C#,JAVA,IOS all anchor tags as their landing pages were separate.

I thaught of a solution and it worked fine would like to ask whether its the correct way from performance point of view as if the data increases then the looping also increases.

```
@foreach (var items in Model.Topics)
{
//Saving the index of each record
var index = Model.Topics.LastIndexOf(items);
//Adding 1 on index as it starts from 0 and matching it with the count of the List.If it matches no comma if it doesn't matches then comma
if (index + 1 == Model.Topics.Count())
{
 <a href="#">@Html.Raw(items.name)</a>
}
else 
  {
  <a href="#">@Html.Raw(items.name),</a>
 }
 }
```

Kindly advice and do post your way of doing the same thing.

Comment: You cannot avoid the loop. but declare `int count = Model.Topics.Count();` before the loop and `if (index + 1 == count)` to avoid running the query in each loop.

Comment: I didn't understood this part.  and if (index + 1 == count) to avoid running the query in each loop

Comment: Because `.Count()` is a linq query. In order to calculate the result of that query, it must iterate over each item in the collection to determine how many items are in the collection.

Comment: Understood,so as per the requirement my code is correct?

Comment: There are many ways you could do it, but what your doing is fine (except for the point I mentioned previously)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,how do I mark your solution as accepted.